# Why does C++ allow you to reference a declared variable in the initial definition?

Tags: c++, standards

The following program compiles and runs just fine.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    size_t foo = sizeof(foo);
    cout << foo << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using the compilation command

```
clang++ -o wut -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -ansi test.cc
```

I understand that this is *probably* the equivalent of

```
size_t foo;
foo = sizeof(foo);
```

Which makes more sense.

However, the initial statement breaks my mind a bit since I think of the RHS being evaluated prior to the LHS (or overall statement) being executed - which in this case might suggest that `foo` doesn't yet exist.

However, my assumption is that `size_t foo` always results in a declaration first, being broken out into its own statement during compile-time, followed by the definition.

Is my assumption correct? Is this governed/well defined in the specification(s)? If so, which section(s)? I realize I compiled with `-ansi` but this appears to work, without error, on all standard versions I tried it with.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Of course the program is meaningless. Thanks for the somewhat obvious. I never said it was valid, just that it compiled with no warnings/errors under clang. I asked, specifically, for the section of the standard that governs this or whether or not it was well defined. Feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It is well defined without the `std::cout`. And that can be fixed by switching to `std::uintptr_t`

Comment: A perhaps related question: Do you think it should be valid to refer to `this` in a constructor?

Comment: Maybe `size_t foo = sizeof(foo);` would be a better example?

Comment: It seems like the following: `I = me`... hmm I sure hope so!

Comment: @KerrekSB Of course. A memory block has already been allocated and the semantics clearly indicate that the constructor is an extra function - the `new` syntax is purely sugar.

Comment: Thanks @1201ProgramAlarm - it is indeed.

Comment: @Qtx: I didn't mention `new` anywhere... memory for your variable has also already been allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [basic.scope.pdecl]:

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 11) and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below.

So once it gets to the `=`, the definition of `foo` is complete (which is also a declaration) and it can be referred to in its own initializer.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Qix Interesting, because it isn't saying *why* this is the case.

Comment: @juanchopanza Because it's the standard...? That's what the standard dictates. That's what I was looking for. I wasn't asking what was running through Ritchie's head when he decided some of that. That wasn't the point of the OP.